# Curl - Make a voice call with a timeout in using sinch

Tags: sinch

How can I make a missed call or a call with a time out using sinch . 
using a curl request

Before a call I should able to select a `DID` which I already have .

Example :

```
curl --user "applicationyour_app_key:your_app_secret" --data '{"message":"your_message"}' -H 'Content-Type: application/json' https://messagingapi.sinch.com/v1/sms/the_phone_number
```

Above shows a query for SMS . Here my question is how to make the call with a time duration of 1 sec after ring using a `DID`

Comment: What plattform are you developing in? i would probably make a call in the calldidend method when the call ends with a noanwer reason.

Answer (score 0):

Send the SMS with you backend from you client when you receive the calldidend event with reason noanswer. if you tell me what plattforms you are using I could give you sample code

Comment: i'm developing on python Python